# when using object variable from baseController in view i get an error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use a custom variable in codeigniter baseController for setting bootstrap settings later in the frontend view

When trying to display the title of the theme set (dark) i get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in
> App\Views\index.php

Thank you for your help ( i am new to php, please explain what is wrong)

---

**BaseController.php**

```
public $pageSettings = [
    'dark' => [
        'title' => 'Dark Site Title',
        'navigation' => true,
    ],
    'light' => [
        'title' => 'Light Site Title',
        'navigation' => false
    ]
];
public $bootstrapTheme = 'dark';

public function view($page = 'home')
{
    $data['theme'] = $this->bootstrapTheme;
    $data['pageSettings'] = $this->pageSettings;     // <-- HERE I set the obj variable
    echo view('templates/index', $data);
}
```

**View\index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageSettings[$theme]->title;?></title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing an *array as an object* in your **index.php**

**Change this:**

```
echo $pageSettings[$theme]->title;
```

**To:**

```
echo $pageSettings[$theme]['title'];
```

Comment: I dont understand you. In this line: $this->pageSettings I set an object variable. Why is it now an array?

Comment: `public $pageSettings = [` is assigned an array. You are just accessing $this and retrieve from that `$this`-object this $pageSettings array and send it to the view. It has never been an object. You are just grabbing it from the $this-Object you assigned it to.